# How To Properly Do 108 Surya Namaskars per Hindu Scriptures

Tags: yoga, meditation, surya

I was proud of myself for doing 108 Surya Namaskars for my Birthday couple of years back (took me about 50 minutes)

Unfortunately it injured my right knee, and I had to stop.

I really want to do 108 Surya Namaskars again and enjoy the benefits mentioned in Hindu Scriptures. How to do this?

Comment: so, you already did it 2 years back.. but forgot now ?

Comment: I never did it properly hence the knee injury

Comment: Better consult an experienced Yoga teacher,  as you might have injured yourself 2 years ago by studying the yoga in a book or so. Please take advise on of a yoga teacher